# What are basic differences between these phrases for a graphic designer in graphic design?

Tags: design-principles, designers, advertising

There are mainly 4 phrases I'm confused with:

1. VK Design
2. VK Designs
3. VK Graphic
4. VK Graphics

where VK is my name.

My motive is to use them on my social media pages. But let's not discuss about that as it may go off topic.

So the ultimate aim is to know the difference (if any) between these 4 phrases and to find out which is correct and which is incorrect to represent following things mainly:

*a) Logo design*

*b) Social media creatives design*

*c) Poster design*

*d) Ad designs for social media*

*e) Print design*

Also, I'm not looking for a detailed study here. I'm just stuck as I feel I'm not able to understand these as I'm not good at English. So a simple explanation would suffice.

The confusion became *more real* when I found out that different graphic design people have already used similar phrases to show their work on social media.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a graphic design question, it's an English language question. Probably better to ask on [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).  Sorry about that. But for what it's worth, No. 3 looks a bit weird to me. The others are fine.

Comment: I do freelance frontend development. I don't call it "Zach Saucier Frontend Development" I just say I'm a frontend developer. Formally (i.e. for taxes and such) I go by "Zach Saucier Web Development" but for websites and social media no one wants to read that. Just go by your name. Say you're a graphic designer.

Comment: Take out no.2 & 3 then flip a coin.

Comment: @Take out means removing 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *general* --

- Design = A plan for an artistic endeavor. Could be environmental, architectural, informational, etc.
- Graphic = An image.
- Without the "s" these would naturally refer more to *the company, organization, or individual*.
- With the "s" there's more a conation of referring to *the work* produced.

Truth is the market is so flooded that these minute difference won't amount to much of anything. It's the work that will inevitably matter. What moniker you use won't assist or deter anything.

Comment: Although because graphic has secondary meaning graphics is more self evident.

Comment: Cool. If I've understood well, it means Vikas Graphic also makes sense if I had a graphic design company. But those 2 comments under question have shown least preference to Graphic. So I'm a bit confused. (confused about Graphic. Design thing is clear now).